# Android app to make quick text notes

Tags: android, note-taking

Sometimes I need to write an address down, or a reference number etc.

I've found that natively there's isn't really anything to do this.

There is SNote - but that application is not light weight at all.

It would be quite nice to be able to use the stylus (Galaxy Note 4), but that's not essential.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Google Keep](//keep.google.com/), which is a nifty little tool where your notes can be synchronized across the devices, and also be readily available on your smart phone.

I'm using this to keep ticket references, airplane references, etc on the front screen of my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact when travelling so that it's accessible when unlocking the device. Should work nicely on your Galaxy as well.

Comment: Google Keep will also let you take list notes, sound notes, photo-notes, and combinations of those and comes with nice resizable widgets.

Answer (score 2):

### [JotterPad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x)

JotterPad is a plain text editor with Markdown support. It is a lightweight application and has a clean and distraction-free interface.

Key Features:

- Word/phrase search capability
- Undo & Redo
- Word and character count
- Automatic saving on exit
- Can be connected to Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Google Keep alternative and settled with Omni Notes.

### Omni Notes

**License :** Open source - GNU GPL v3.0

**Price**   : Free (as of now)

**Availability on** : [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/it.feio.android.omninotes.foss/) and [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.feio.android.omninotes)

**Features** (verbatim):

- Material Design interface
- Basic add, modify, archive, trash and delete notes actions
- Share, merge and search notes
- Image, audio and generic file attachments
- Manage your notes using tags and categories
- To-do list
- Sketch-note mode
- Notes shortcut on home screen
- Export/import notes to backup
- Google Now integration: just tell "write a note" followed by the content
- Multiple widgets, DashClock extension, Android 4.2 lockscreen compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I love JotterPad recommended by @Tymric but it's not lightweight. Look no further than [StatusNote2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ipaulpro.statusnotes&hl=en_IE), it's brilliant.

- Add quick notes and reminders to your status bar while using any application.
- Create unlimited notification notes with over 100 memorable icons.